# "Task 'Files' not found in root project 'GradleProjectTest'. " - while building gradle project in jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, gradle, jenkins-pipeline

I have a simple gradle project and I have set up a pipeline in jenkins. The pipeline script I wrote as below:

```
    node(){
      def server
      def buildInfo
      def rtGradle

      stage('Clone') {
        try{

          git credentialsId: '2d5e31ac-103b-4e05-8f69-6feaa548b35c', url: 'https://kousik19@bitbucket.org/kousik19/gradleproject.git'


        }
        catch(Exception e){
           println(e.getMessage())

        }
      }
      stage('ArtifactoryConfigurationMaven') {
        try{

        }
        catch(Exception e){
           println(e.getMessage())

        }
      }
      stage('ArtifactoryConfigurationGradle') {
        try{

           server = Artifactory.newServer url: 'http://localhost:8040/artifactory', username: 'admin', password: 'password'


          buildInfo = Artifactory.newBuildInfo()


          rtGradle.tool = "gradle"
          rtGradle.deployer repo:'grtest', server: server
          rtGradle.resolver repo:'grtest', server: server


        }
        catch(Exception e){
           println(e.getMessage())

        }
      }
      stage('GradleBuild') {
        try{

          buildInfo = rtGradle.run rootDir: "C:/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins/workspace/gradlePipeline", buildFile: 'build.gradle', tasks: 'clean artifactoryPublish'


        }
        catch(Exception e){
           println(e.getMessage())

        }
      }
      stage('Publish') {
        try{

          server.publishBuildInfo buildInfo


        }
        catch(Exception e){
           println(e.getMessage())

        }
      }
    }
```

But each time I am getting an error as follow with full stacktrace:

- What went wrong:
  Task 'Files' not found in root project 'GradleProjectTest'.

  - Exception is:

```java
org.gradle.execution.TaskSelectionException: Task 'Files' not found in root project 'GradleProjectTest'.
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskSelector.getSelection(TaskSelector.java:116)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskSelector.getSelection(TaskSelector.java:81)
    at org.gradle.execution.commandline.CommandLineTaskParser.parseTasks(CommandLineTaskParser.java:42)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskNameResolvingBuildConfigurationAction.configure(TaskNameResolvingBuildConfigurationAction.java:44)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:48)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTasksBuildExecutionAction.configure(DefaultTasksBuildExecutionAction.java:44)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:48)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.execution.ExcludedTaskFilteringBuildConfigurationAction.configure(ExcludedTaskFilteringBuildConfigurationAction.java:47)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:48)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.select(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$CalculateTaskGraph.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:268)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.constructTaskGraph(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:175)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:130)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:109)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:78)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:152)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:100)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:75)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:51)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:32)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:45)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:82)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:295)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
```

Can you please give a bit insight what I am doing wrong? I am not very much expert on gradle build with jenkins.

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with the rootDir name. It's taking C:/Program as the directory and Files as another parameter.

You can try:

- getting the whole string in single quotes

  ```
  buildInfo = rtGradle.run rootDir: "'C:/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins/workspace/gradlePipeline'", buildFile: 'build.gradle', tasks: 'clean artifactoryPublish'
  ```
- using an environment variable

  ```
  buildInfo = rtGradle.run rootDir: "%programfiles(x86)%/Jenkins/workspace/gradlePipeline", buildFile: 'build.gradle', tasks: 'clean artifactoryPublish'
  ```
- usually all pipeline steps run commands from the job workspace, so you might be able to omit the parameter or use a dot

  ```
  buildInfo = rtGradle.run rootDir: ".", buildFile: 'build.gradle', tasks: 'clean artifactoryPublish'
  ```

Edit: last option worked for this question.

Comment: @KOUSIKMANDAL Did you try all 3? Are you still getting the same error?

Comment: Yes. I did. Later I figured out it was permission issue on that folder. After fixing the permission issue it worked well.

Comment: @KOUSIKMANDAL Cool. Did it work with your initial code or did you use any of the alternatives above?

Comment: I used rtGradle.run rootDir: "."

Comment: @KOUSIKMANDAL I've edited my answer to point which option worked, would you mind accepting the answer, please.